# t-distribution in confidence intervals and corresponding ti84 commands

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test

In computing confidence intervals for population means and variances, I have come across the use of the t-test for the computations of certain intervals.

For example, the formula given for the confidence interval of μ with σ unknown is: ( x̄ - t(n-1, α/2)(S/sqrt(n)), x̄ + t(n-1, α/2)(S/sqrt(n)) )

The problem arises in determining what values to use for the critical values for the t-test and how to express it in the ti-84. I've tried looking up values in t-tables, but I'm never sure whether to use one or two tailed values, so I end up with inconsistent results. Intuition tells me that I should use the values for two sided t tests, but I don't know quite how to interpret the tables accordingly. Also, the results in the table never match the values my calculator gives me when I use the "tpdf" function.

For example, if I am to compute a 95% confidence interval with 60 degrees of freedom, what commands do I put in my ti84 to execute the t-test part of the confidence interval?

To do this I would use the "tpdf" command in the ti84 to get tpdf(60, .025)=1.022*10^-4, but ttable.org tells me that I should get 1.671 or 2.000 (depending on one tail or two. again, I'm not sure how to make this distinction).

Same goes for chi-square commands within the same context, I'm not sure how to accurately enter them into my calculator to solve confidence intervals.

(I know this isn't classically the type of question asked on here, but any & all help is appreciated :) )

Comment: I do not know about ti84, but obviously, you should use cdf, instead of pdf.

Comment: terrific, thank you! now, what would I put for the upper & lower bounds when using to solve confidence intervals like the one I mentioned above? if I put tcdf(-999, .025, 60), I get .5099 instead of 1.671 or 2.000 shown in t tables...

Comment: actually, would it not be the inverse t command?

Comment: inverse of cdf. If no inverse of cdf function in ti84, try tcdf(-999,x,60) using different x, until you get 0.975, then that x is the t value you need for CI.